# Why is the balloon not spawning in the bottom?

Tags: python

I am writing a game in Python using software called [PictoBlox](https://pictoblox.ai/). In my game there is an arrow and a balloon, when the balloon reaches the Y axis 211, it is supposed to spawn again from the bottom. Everything else is working, but this respawn isn't happening.

This is the code for a balloon:

```py
balloon = Sprite('Balloon1')

import time
import random

balloon.gotoxy(random.randint(-210, 200), -257)
print("Let's get poppin!")
balloon.show()

while True:
  balloon.changey(2)
  if balloon.y == 211:
    balloon.hide()
    time.sleep(1)
    balloon.gotoxy(random.randint(-210, 200), -257)
    balloon.show()
    balloon.changey(2)
    
  if balloon.istouching('Arrow1'):
    balloon.hide()
    balloon.gotoxy(random.randint(-210, 200), -257)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    balloon.show()
    print("Point!")
```

This is the code for an arrow:

```py
sprite = Sprite('Arrow1')

import time

sprite.setrotationstyle('left-right')

while True:
  if sprite.iskeypressed('up arrow'):
    sprite.changey(6.5)
  if sprite.iskeypressed('down arrow'):
    sprite.changey(-6.5)
  if sprite.iskeypressed('right arrow'):
    sprite.changex(6.5)
  if sprite.iskeypressed('left arrow'):
    sprite.changex(-6.5)
```

Here is a link to my code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/YLHA

I tried the code above and what I expected was that when the arrow touches the balloon it disappears (pops). That is working fine, but when the balloon reaches the Y axis 211, it is supposed to spawn again from the bottom, but it isn't happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an assumption, but what went wrong is probably just the first if-statement you have in your "baloon code" at

```py
if balloon.y == 211:
```

Change it to

```py
if balloon.y > 211:
```

Explaination of my assumption:

Since you are always incrementing baloon's Y coordinate by 2 units and the starting Y coordinate is randomized, it has ~50% of being an EVEN number, so that after the increment of Y by 2 units it would still be an EVEN number, but in your if-statement you are checking if baloon's Y coordinate is equal to 211, which is an ODD number, thus it will just jump over (... 208 -> 210 -> 212 ...) and will not go inside the if-statement.

That's why you should just check if baloon's Y coordinate is GREATER THAN the upper bound (211).

Answer (score 0):

your changing in steps of 2 so its possible for it to go from 210 to 212 without it equaling 211? Maybe check if the value is >= 211.

```
if balloon.y >= 211:
    balloon.hide()
    ...
```